# Correlation between time series

Tags: machine-learning, time-series, data-science

I have a dataset where a process is described as a time series made of ~2000 points and 1500 dimensions.

I would like to quantify how much each dimension is correlated with another time series measured by another method.

What is the appropriate way to do this (eventually done in python) ? I have heard that Pearson is not well suited for this task, at least without data preparation. What are your thoughts about that?

Many thanks!

Comment: Could you tell us a bit more about the nature of your data? In the general case, I would expect Pearson correlation to work just fine. Is there something special about your data?

Comment: Unfortunately I cannot say much about it, but roughly the data comes from the monitoring of a mechanical system (described by unnamed variables so no expert knowledge a priori) over time.

Answer (score 2):

A general good rule in data science is to first try the easy thing. Only when the easy thing fails should you move to something more complicated. With that in mind, here is how you would compute the Pearson correlation between each dimension and some other time series. The key function here being [`pearsonr`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.stats.pearsonr.html):

```
import numpy as np
from scipy.stats import pearsonr

# Generate a random dataset using 2000 points and 1500 dimensions
n_times = 2000
n_dimensions = 1500
data = np.random.rand(n_times, n_dimensions)

# Generate another time series, also using 2000 points
other_time_series = np.random.rand(n_times)

# Compute correlation between each dimension and the other time series
correlations = np.zeros(n_dimensions)
for dimension in range(n_dimensions):
    # The Pearson correlation function gives us both the correlation
    # coefficient (r) and a p-value (p). Here, we only use the coefficient.
    r, p = pearsonr(data[:, dimension], other_time_series)
    correlations[dimension] = r

# Now we have, for each dimension, the Pearson correlation with the other time
# series!
len(correlations)

# Print the first 5 correlation coefficients
print(correlations[:5])
```

If Pearson correlation doesn't work well for you, you can try swapping out the `pearsonr` function with something else, like:

- [`spearmanr`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.stats.spearmanr.html#scipy.stats.spearmanr)    Spearman rank-order correlation coefficient.
- [`kendalltau`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.stats.kendalltau.html#scipy.stats.kendalltau)    Kendall’s tau, a correlation measure for ordinal data.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Actually this is quite close to what I tried, I was more interested about the methodology to use for time series correlation and if Pearson is relevant for the problem. That's why I did not provide a code example :) Maybe the underlying question is more : if I want to calculate a correlation coefficient, should I preprocess the data in some way or use another method than Pearson coefficent. Cheers

Comment: Whether your data needs preprocessing depends on the nature of your data. Generally, as long all your timeseries are plain floating point numbers, you don't need preprocessing. Pearson correlation is insensitive to the data mean and overall scaling of the data.

Comment: Of course, Pearson correlation can be sensitive to outliers, so if your data has some artefacts/glitches, that can be a problem.

Comment: OK, there are indeed glitches and noise in the data, the process depends on external factors. So it is kind of expected since it is part of the observed process.

Comment: Noob question : why would Spearman or Kendall Tau "work better" ?

Comment: You would use Spearman rank correlation or Kendall's Tau when you only care about whether one timeseries goes up as another timeseries goes up, regardless of how much it goes up.